# Android/Eclipse moved workspace from one computer to another computer

Tags: android, eclipse

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953458/1074880 I followed these instruction but didn't know what file to select after checking in my project properties.

Properties > Libraries (Unable to get system library for the project, Access rules: No rules defined, Native library location: (None)) > Add External JARs > program file > java > jre6 is it lib or bin then what do I select after that?

Errors:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The project was not built
>   since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
>   java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this
>   project           Unknown Java Problem The project was not built since its
>   build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
>   java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this
>   project       Unknown Java Problem The type java.lang.Object cannot be
>   resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   The
>   type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced
>   from required .class files     Unable to resolve target
>   'android-8'       Unknown Android Target Problem Unable to resolve target
>   'android-8' until the SDK is loaded.      Unknown Android Target Problem
>   Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8'          Unknown Android
>   Target Problem Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8'
>   until the SDK is loaded.      Unknown Android Target Problem

Answer (score 1):

One solution is simply to import project. Then clean, if it doesn't work, delete project, then import again. I assume you click copy content to local when you import.

Another solution is to make a new android project and select create project from existing source.

Whatever solution is used you still sometimes have to do it multiple times for it to work...

Comment: I am currently trying these solutions http://stackoverflow.com/a/6459478/1074880 http://stackoverflow.com/a/5576835/1074880

Comment: This is pain in the *** for me as well, updated answer with another possible solution.

Comment: *"This is pain in the *** for me as well..."* - that's got to be one of the dumbest design choices in the history of IDEs...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the some steps If you want to move your project to one PC to other, hope this help.
When you are copy to Pen drive or Hard drive follow these steps

1. Open Eclipse and switch to Workspace1 using
   Switch To Workspace...
2. Check the projects in Workspace1
3. Switch to another workspace to make sure that Workspace1
   is closed completely by Eclipse (Critical step!)
4. Quit Eclipse
5. Copy Workspace1 and name the copy Workspace2
6. Copy Workspace2 to a USB flash drive
7. Copy Workspace2 from the USB flash drive onto the hard disk
   of a different computer
8. Open Eclipse on the new computer
9. Switch to Workspace2 using Switch To Workspace...

The projects open normally from Eclipse on any machine as though
that workspace had been there all along. The critical step seems
to be switching to another workspace before quitting Eclipse. If
you skip that step the copied and transferred workspace does not
open correctly.